# mySQL queries queue system

Tags: mysql, performance, queue

I know this question is generic but hopefully someone knows mySQL under the bonnet.

I'm wondering how does mySQL server (versions 5.5.7 to 5.7 are the ones we use) **assign priorities** when running multiple queries -Q1, Q2, Q3- at the same time.

- Does it *balance processor time equally* between the 3 queries: 1/3
  each?

  Does it allocate *more computing power for larger queries*, kind of estimating, e.g. 2/3 Q1, 1/6 for Q2-Q3?

Reason behind my question is why servers freeze when running multiple deliveries.  It seems that if Q1 is massive, the servers would not put it in the queue and allow Q2-Q3 to stay on hold for hours, keeping always a minimum to keep delivering.

Truth is our server can get close to freezing, even for relatively small queries, suggesting that there is *a pure FIFO queue* (first in, first out)? allocating so little power to simpler queries Q2-Q3 that these could not complete for hours, until Q1 finishes. This cannot be the case but I struggle then to see why it blocks.

Comment: Apart from disk access, which gets some special treatment, queries are basically executed without regards to other queries. Still, they will block each other because of locking. If one of your queries e.g. wants to update a row (or in case you are using MyISAM: a table) the other one uses, depending on the situaiton it might have to wait until the lock is lifted. Long running queries are often longrunning because they use (and maybe lock) many resources. Try to optimize your query (e.g. speed it up, add indexes to lock less, split it up in smaller parts, use other transactions settings, ...)

Comment: Thanks I knew a bit about the locking (per row, per table, depending on the engine  -we have InnoDB). I don't get what you mean by "without regards to other queries".
Oversimplifying: So if Q1 takes 1h, and Q2 takes 1s, will mySQL process Q1 first, and the output of Q2 will be available in 1h 1s?  Or it will run both on parallel and Q2 will take longer than running alone?

Comment: Yes, every client gets its own thread. Q1 and Q2 will run in parallel if they do not lock each other.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many things possibly going on to give you an answer.  At least, not without more info.

- How many CPU cores do you have?  3 queries *should* be able to run simultaneously if you have that many cores.  But if they are all I/O-bound, then they slow each other down.
- Are you using InnoDB?  It is much better at concurrent access than MyISAM.  Especially if an `UPDATE` is involved -- MyISAM writes and reads block each other; InnoDB does not suffer from such conflicts.
- Is there some form of transaction involved?
- Is a table scan involved?
- Is the Query cache enabled?  What is `query_cache_size`?  If it is more than 50M, then there are certain inefficiencies that you may be stumbling over.
- What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM?  How big is the dataset that needs to be touched to perform the queries?  These *may* be interacting to cause I/O, or worse, swapping.
- A query that takes 1 hour is terrible.  A few minutes is 'bad'.  Let's see the queries.
- There are many more details that would determine whether multiple *InnoDB* queries will run slower or faster depending on whether they are run in parallel.

If you want an answer other than hand-waving, please provide the queries and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for any tables involved.  Plus indicate how big the tables are.